# Unable to get pyramid like image in Java

Tags: java

[image: Reference Image]

Above is the image, I am trying to achieve, I am almost close to the logic but not exactly there, any idea where am I missing

```
class GFG  
{ 
static void printSierpinski(int n) 
{ 
    for (int y = n - 1; y >= 0; y--) { 

        // printing space till 
        // the value of y 
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) { 
            System.out.print(" "); 
        } 

        // printing '*' 
        for (int x = 0; x + y < n; x++) { 

            // printing '*' at the appropriate 
            // position is done by the and  
            // value of x and y wherever value 
            // is 0 we have printed '*' 
            if ((x & y) != 0) 
                System.out.print(" "
                                + " "); 
            else
                System.out.print("* "); 
        } 

        System.out.print("\n"); 
    } 
} 

// Driver code 
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    int n = 16; 

    // Function calling 
    printSierpinski(n); 
}
```

}

Comment: It would be a nice thing to show what the *current* code is producing.

Comment: you should put an image about the exit that you want

Comment: Write a method that produces a blank String that's n characters long.  Write a method that produces an asterisk string that's n characters long.  Figure out how to call these methods for each line you want to print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the following output in about an hour.  I'm not going to post my code.  I'm going to explain how I tackled the problem in the hopes that the OP and others will learn something about logic.

```
                 *                 
                * *                
               * * *               
              * * * *              
             * * * * *             
            * * * * * *            
           * * * * * * *           
          * * * * * * * *          
         * * * * * * * * *         
        *                 *        
       * *               * *       
      * * *             * * *      
     * * * *           * * * *     
    * * * * *         * * * * *    
   * * * * * *       * * * * * *   
  * * * * * * *     * * * * * * *  
 * * * * * * * *   * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

The first thing I did was write a method to create a String.  This method took a char and int length as parameters.  The result of the method was either a blank String or an asterisk String.  When I created the asterisk String, I inserted the blank spaces in between the asterisks.

Once I got that method working, I printed the bottom line.  Then I printed the line before the bottom line.  At this point, I wasn't concerned about for loops or while loops or any other kind of fruit loops.  I wanted to see what the logical pattern was.

I printed the bottom 5 lines before I deduced the pattern.  Once I understood the logic, then I wrote the for loop.  Ok, at this point I have half the pyramid done.

I printed a couple of rows of the upper pyramid before I understood the logic of the upper pyramid.  Once I understood the logic, it was simple to write the upper pyramid for loop.

After I finished the code, I realized I could generalize the code to create pyramids with any width base.  That's why I posted the 9 level pyramid at the beginning of this answer.

The moral of my story is work to understand the logic first, even if you have to write some ugly code to help you understand.  I'm a somewhat experienced developer and I had to experiment a bit to figure out the logic.

Once you understand the logic, then you can write beautiful code.